# How to pull correct mysql from testcontainer using Quarkus

Tags: mysql, docker, quarkus, testcontainers

I using testcontainer and macbook m1. When i start testContainer it thow me error:

Could not pull image: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries

I can't understand why because when i using postgres it ok.

Here is my config. Please help

```
open class MySqlResourceTest : QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {
    private val DATABASE: SpecifiedMySQLContainer = SpecifiedMySQLContainer("mysql:5.7.8").apply {
        withDatabaseName("test")
        withUsername("abc")
        withPassword("123456")
        withExposedPorts(3317)
    }

    override fun start(): MutableMap<String, String> {
        DATABASE.start()
        DATABASE.setCommand()
        return Collections.singletonMap("quarkus.datasource.url", DATABASE.jdbcUrl)
    }

    override fun stop() {
        DATABASE.stop()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to run that image manually via docker run?

Comment: When i start using docker-compose i must using platform: linux/x86_64 it then work. But when testcontainer i can't understand how to overider platform

Comment: This sounds like something you should report this on the testcontainers issue tracker

Answer (score 0):

Common testcontainer for MySql is `org.testcontainers.containers.MySQLContainer`. You're using a SpecifiedMySQLContainer in your code snippet, which may cause the issue.